# SQL OLEDB call hanging

Tags: c++, sql-server, oledb, atl

I've got an issue where a thread simply hangs and never returns after calling the SQL OLE DB CCommand< Taccessor, TRowset >::Open() command using the Microsoft's Active Template Library.

Here's what the call looks like:

```
hr = CCommand< TAccessor, TRowset >::Open( DB::Instance()->GetSession(), CComBSTR(strCmd), pPropSet, pRowsAffected, DBGUID_DEFAULT, true, 0 );
```

The CCommand<>::Open() method is executing a stored procedure on a SQL Server across the network.

I managed to capture a stack trace from Process Explorer, and just looking for any clues or suggestions on a direction to help figure what's going on here..  I've included the stack trace below:

```
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMultipleObjects+0xc0a
ntoskrnl.exe!KeAcquireSpinLockAtDpcLevel+0x732
ntoskrnl.exe!KeWaitForMutexObject+0x19f
ntoskrnl.exe!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xde
ntoskrnl.exe!KeSynchronizeExecution+0x3a23
wow64cpu.dll!TurboDispatchJumpAddressEnd+0x6c0
wow64cpu.dll!TurboDispatchJumpAddressEnd+0x4a8
wow64.dll!Wow64SystemServiceEx+0x1ce
wow64.dll!Wow64LdrpInitialize+0x429
ntdll.dll!RtlIsDosDeviceName_U+0x24c87
ntdll.dll!LdrInitializeThunk+0xe
ntdll.dll!ZwWaitForSingleObject+0x15
ntdll.dll!RtlIntegerToUnicodeString+0x20b
MSDART.DLL!?ConvertExclusiveToShared@CReaderWriterLock3AR@@QAEXXZ+0xb8
sqloledb.dll!DllUnregisterServer+0xa29b
sqloledb.dll!DllUnregisterServer+0xa05b
sqloledb.dll!DllUnregisterServer+0x9f70
sqloledb.dll+0x16e92
MyService.exe+0xea26a
```

This code had been working just fine for many years.   This is a 32 bit C++ app, built with MS Visual Studio 2010.   We started having issues after 2 changes happened and not sure if it's related or not, one the 32 bit built app is now running on a 64 bit Windows environment for the first time..  and two, the sql database is no longer local on the server, but is across the network.

This is a high volume server running hundreds or even thousands of transactions per minute, and every few days or longer, it's quite random, the code will just hang in the exact same spot, with the exact same stack trace as above..

Really would appreciate any suggestions as to how to figure out what's going on with sqloledb??

First question to start is why does the stack trace show that sqloledb is calling DllUnregisterServer?

From the stack trace it appears sql ole db is waiting for something with the WaitForMultipleObjects as the last call, but how can I figure out what it's waiting for?

Thank you.